# When to add what indexes in a table in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a question about Rails database.

- Should I add "index" to all the foreign keys like "xxx_id"?
- Should I add "index" to the automatically created "id" column?
- Should I add "index(unique)" to the automatically created "id" column?
- If I add index to two foreign keys at once (`add_index (:users, [:category, :state_id])`, what happens? How is this different from adding the index for each key?

  ```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.integer :category_id 
        t.integer :state_id
        t.string :email
        t.boolean :activated
        t.timestamps
      end
    # Do I need this? Is it meaningless to add the index to the primary key?
    # If so, do I need :unique => true ?
    add_index :users, :id 
    # I don't think I need ":unique => true here", right?
    add_index :users, :category_id # Should I need this?
    add_index :users, :state_id # Should I need this?
    # Are the above the same as the following?
    add_index (:users, [:category, :state_id])
    end
  end
  ```

---

Great answer so far. Additional question.

- I should add "index with unique" for xxx_id, right?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

> Should I add "index" to all the foreign keys like "xxx_id"?

It would be better, because it accelerates the search in sorting in this column. And Foreign keys are something searched for a lot.

Since Version 5 of rails the index will be created automatically, for more information see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/migrations.html).

> Should I add "index" to the automatically created "id" column?

No, this is already done by rails

> Should I add "index(unique)" to the automatically created "id" column?

No, same as above

> If I add index to two foreign keys at once (`add_index (:users, [:category_id, :state_id])`, what happens? How is this different from adding the index for each key?

Then the index is a combined index of the two columns. That doesn't make any sense, unless  you want all entries for one `category_id` **AND** one `state_id` (It should be `category_id` not `category`) at the same time.

An Index like this would speed the following request up:

```
# rails 2
User.find(:all, :conditions => { :state_id => some_id, :category_id => some_other_id })

# rails 3
User.where(:state_id => some_id, :category_id => some_other_id)
```

Where

```
add_index :users, :category_id
add_index :users, :state_id
```

will speed up these requests:

```
# rails 2+3
User.find_by_category_id(some_id)
User.find_by_state_id(some_other_id)

# or
# rails 2
User.find(:all, :conditions => {:category_id => some_id})
User.find(:all, :conditions => {:state_id => some_other_id})

# rails 3
User.where(:category_id => some_id)
User.where(:state_id => some_other_id)
```

> I should add "index with unique" for xxx_id, right?

No, because if you do this, only one user can be in one category, but the meaning of category is that you can put more **many** user into one category. In your `User` model you have something like this `belongs_to :category` and in your Category model something like `has_many :users`. If you have a `has_many` relationship the `foreign_key` field must not be unique!

For more detailed information on this you should take a look at [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman)'s great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658859/when-to-add-what-indexes-in-a-table-in-rails/3661096#3661096).

Comment: Great answer. Additional question. I should add "index with unique" for xxx_id, right?

Comment: Question, would you index a foreign key if that field is very rarely searched explicitly?

Comment: @Cyle I can't answer this definitely, it depends on your machine, the size of the database, and the nature of your query. If the query comes from the web I would probably say YES, because it's always better to get fast responses, if it is for a background job and you need to save disk space you don't need to set it, but if the disk space is not an issue I would add an index anyway.

Answer (score 115):

Indexing can be a tricky, subtle thing, but there are general rules that apply that can make determining which to use a lot easier.

The first thing to remember is that indexes can work in more than one way. An index on A, B, C also works for A, B and simply A, so you can design your indexes to be more versatile if you order them correctly. The phone book is indexed on Last Name, First Name, so you can look up people easily by their last name, or a combination of last name and first name. You cannot, however, look them up directly by their first name. You'd need a separate index for that. The same goes for phone number, which you would have to index as well.

With that in mind, there are many things that will dictate how you create indexes:

- If you have a `belongs_to`-`has_many` relationship pairing, you need to have an index on the foreign key used.
- If you order your records, and there is a large number of them that will be paginated, you should add that order column to the end of the index.
- If you have a `has_many :through` relationship, your join table should have a unique index on both properties involved in the join as a compound key.
- If you fetch a record directly using a unique identifier such as username or email, that should be a unique index.
- If you fetch sets of records from a `has_many` relationship using a scope, make sure there's an index that includes the `has_many` foreign key and the scope column in that order.

The goal with indexes is to eliminate the dreaded "table scan" or "file sort" operations that occur when your data is not indexed properly.

In simple terms, look at the queries being generated by your application and ensure that columns referenced in `WHERE` or `HAVING` conditions and `ORDER BY` clauses are represented in that order.

Comment: I'm curious why Rails doesn't imply indexes if you always want to use them for every foreign key. Is there a situation where it's not a good idea to index it?

Comment: @trip It's pretty easy to add `index: true` to your column definition for simple cases, but sometimes you might want more control over it. Having indexes by default on foreign keys isn't a terrible default to have, but it might catch people by surprise.

Answer (score 15):

- Always index foreign keys
- Always index columns you will order by
- All unique fields (to ensure uniqueness at a database level. Example migration: `add_index :users, :email, unique: true`)
- If you order by two things, or search by two things, for example:
  `order by [a, b]` or `find where( a and b )`, then you need a double index:

Concrete example:

If you have:

```
default_scope :order => 'photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC'
```

You should add:

```
add_index :photos, [:created_at, :version]
```

Note:
An index takes up extra space on the disk and makes it slower to create and update each record, because it has to rebuild each index.

Credit:

https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-choosing-additional-indexes, [rails - created_at when user for ordering, Should you add an Index to the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445507/rails-created-at-when-user-for-ordering-should-you-add-an-index-to-the-table), and the answers above.