# rails - created_at when user for ordering, Should you add an Index to the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello for one of my models photos I have:

```
default_scope :order => 'photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC'
```

Given that I'm ordering by CREATED_AT and Version... Should I have a DB index on CREATED_AT?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a best practice to do so. But maybe it won't make a difference in speed because when ordered by id they are (usually) already sorted, and Rails automatically generates an index for id.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following is based on my PostgreSQL experience but would probably also apply for MySQL and others.

If you plan on retrieving a large number of records from this table or making use of pagination, an index on the fields used in the `ORDER BY` would be useful.

You should create an index on all order fields in the same order. If you are mixing `ASC` and `DESC` in your `ORDER BY` you would need to create an index with these specific orderings to take full advantage of the index.

A suitable ActiveRecord migration for your photos table would be:

```
add_index :photos, [:created_at, :version]
```

I would recommend looking at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output with production-like data before and after adding the index to confirm it is having the effect you are after.

Answer (score 25):

One trick that may be helpful: in typical MySql/ActiveRecord models, you will have `id` as a numeric primary key (hence implicitly indexed), which should be in the same order of `created_at` - which means you could order by `id` instead and get the fast performance, without the write cost for an extra index.

Answer (score 10):

Was just reading up on this last night as I was adding indices to a number of tables. The short answer is 'yes'. The case is quite eloquently made here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140426154227/https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-choosing-additional-indexes

The longer answer is also 'yes' but why don't you test it out a bit and see what sort of mileage you get out of it based on how your app interacts with the data.

Comment: Great post. It talks not just about SQL, but also ActiveRecord. You can't force the use of a particular index in PostgreSQL though. Which makes me curious how things work out in ActiveRecord 3 with prepared statements, because the speedup that you get with pg is by avoiding plan analysis each time.